# Chrome modal dialogs don't appear - locks up window

Tags: google-chrome, modal-dialog, windows-10, hidden, invisible

For about the last four months, when using Chrome, any page that opens a modal dialog box, the dialog doesn't appear - but Chrome behaves as though it is there and is unresponsive - it just beeps waiting for the dialog box to be closed.

It doesn't matter if it is a web page - eg Google Calendar, or even the folder selection dialog when saving a bookmark.

I'm using Chrome Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Professional Build 15063.

I have tried everything to fix this, but I think there is a DLL or Windows update or another app that introduced this problem.  I first tried disabling all add-ins.  I can't actually delete any add-ins as the add-in delete option throws a modal dialog which never appears and locks up Chrome.  I can't properly uninstall Chrome as the uninstall also throws a Chrome modal dialog which gives the same error.  I've totally uninstalled Chrome manually, deleted every file in Program Files (32 and 64 bit) under Google, deleted very registry entry with Google as a part of the name or value.  I've searched the user files and deleted what I could find.

But after all this, I reinstall and the issue is back.  In use Chrome on several machines, so it's definitely something on this one machine - not a setting or add-in that is common between all machines when I log in to Chrome and synchronise settings.

The only step left is to reinstall Windows, which I'd like to avoid.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Not sure it's Windows-related, I'm seeing the same issue with Chrome on Ubuntu. The modals still respond to keyboard so you can either escape or confirm, if you know what they are supposed to be saying.

Answer (score 13):

Found the very simple solution. Go to Advanced settings, under System, turn off Use Hardware Acceleration when available.

I found this the day after I refreshed ie essentially reinstalled Windows.

I had tried everything else with no improvement.

Comment: Worked great for me; thanks! 
Chrome `⋮` menu > Settings (then scroll to bottom) > Show advanced settings... > uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available"

Comment: Four years later, ran into this issue while running windows 10 VM with wmware (I have no problem when running chrome in the host!) Thanks!